# Show Related Quantity of Products and Categories in the Search Bar

Tags: magento2, search, related-products, advanced-search

Now in the search bar products and categories are displayed. In the product and category header, I show the **See All** button that redirects to all related products and categories.

I want to show the related items count in the search with the see all button.

Answer (score 0):

Try with get the product search criteria,
**$searchCriterias = $block->getSearchCriterias()**;

**$block->escapeHtml($criteria['value'])** 
we need to loop through the left and right side on the searchCriterias as,

> foreach ($searchCriterias[$side] as $criteria) 
> **$searchCriterias = $block->getSearchCriterias()**;

Comment: In which template I will do this

Comment: Please try to extend the module-catalog-search\view\frontend\templates\advanced\result.phtml in your custom theme

Comment: This is not working

Comment: Can I share my template